# how to Supress warning EJBTHREE-1337:do not get webservice context property

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

im new to webservices.i ran a sample webservice(Jboss5.0.1,jdk 6) from java client. i got this warning. but application runs properly.when i searched about this warning i came to know that we dont need to worry about this. but is there any way to hide this from log?

[StatelessBeanContext]  EJBTHREE-1337: do not get WebServiceContext property from stateless bean context, it should already have been injected

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://idevone.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/howto-suppress-ejbthree-1337-warning/:

> The problem however is that the
>   warning clutters the log file and
>   makes debugging harder than needed. It
>   is easy to suppress it though and I
>   will show you how.
>
> First, locate jboss-log4j.xml file which should be found under
>   ${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/conf. If you are using a runtime
>   configuration other than default, locate the file under configuration
>   that you actually use. This file is used to configure logging output
>   of the JBoss.
>
> Inside the file search for “Limit categories” – you should find a list
>   of  definitions. Edit it to look something like this:
>
> ```
> <!-- ================ -->
> <!-- Limit categories -->
> <!-- ================ -->
>
> <!-- Suppress EJBTHREE-1337 warning -->
> <category name="org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessBeanContext">
>   <priority value="ERROR"/>
> </category>
> ```
>
> You are basically telling JBoss to suppress any WARN or lower messages
>   from the class that generates those warnings. Now just restart JBoss
>   and the warning should disappear.